# Doing operation for each file of a folder using windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I have some document in a folder. these document may have same name with different extention, e.g: xyz.doc, xyz.pdf and xyz.log. I want implement following logic in windows command line script:

```
foreach *.doc {
if EXIST *.pdf{
 do something_1
}else {
  do something_2
}
if EXIST *.log {
 do something_3
}
```

Comment: `for %G in (*.doc) do @if exist "%~nG.pdf" (echo + %~nG ) else (echo -  %~nG)` from `cmd` prompt; use doubled percent signs like `%%G` and `%%~nG` in a `.bat` or `.cmd` script. Guidance in http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: Hi Josef, thanks for response, for all cases, it is going in to else part. it's not working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (`Copy&Paste` from `cmd` window). Used another extensions but principle is the same:

```
==> dir /b "sta *.*"
sta tus.csv
sta tus.txt
sta tus2.txt

==> for %G in ("sta *.txt") do @if exist "%~nG.csv" (echo + %~nG ) else (echo - %~nG)
+ sta tus
- sta tus2

==>
```

A batch script for your extensions:

```
@echo off
for %%G in ("*.doc") do (
    if exist "%%~nG.pdf" (
        echo + %%~nG
    ) else (
        echo - %%~nG
    )
)
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~nG` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)